# if i am using add own data on azure openai and using blob storage what if i updated the data inside the blob storage, how it will update it on chatbot

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai

When utilizing Azure OpenAI and incorporating my own data through blob storage, I'm curious about the process of updating the data within the blob storage and how it impacts the functionality of the chatbot I'm using. Could you please provide insight into how this update mechanism works?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo/blob/main/docs/data_ingestion.md) for Indexing additional documents.
To upload more PDFs, put them in the data/ folder and run ./scripts/prepdocs.sh or ./scripts/prepdocs.ps1.

A recent change added checks to see what's been uploaded before. The prepdocs script now writes an .md5 file with an MD5 hash of each file that gets uploaded. Whenever the prepdocs script is re-run, that hash is checked against the current hash and the file is skipped if it hasn't changed.